# Get CLASSPATH constructed in a .bat file from python

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, cmd

The java project I am working on has a `.bat` file and a `.sh` file which build the `CLASSPATH` for the project to run. (`.bat` for windows and `.sh` for the rest).

Now, I am writing a python script that needs access to the classpath created by these scripts, the one from `.sh` if on linux and the one from `.bat` if on windows.

Currently, I am doing this for linux:

```
Popen(['bash', '-c', '. mkcp.sh && echo $CLASSPATH'], stdout=sp.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
```

And I can't figure out an equivalent way to do this on windows. So far I've come up with this

```
check_output(['cmd', '/c', 'call mkcp.bat && echo %CLASSPATH%'])
```

But that puts all the commands in the `mkcp.bat` file into the stdout. (Adding `@echo off` to that file is not an option for me, i.e., I can't modify it). That problem aside, the main problem is that the `%CLASSPATH%` is substituted with its value *before* the batch file is run, which is not what I want.

Another approach I thought of was if I create a `Popen` object as above and run the batch file and if I can access the environment of that process, I can get what I want. But from Popen's documentation, this doesn't look to be possible.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to create a batch file with the relevant commands. That way the variable doesn't get expanded until CMD processes the relevant line. Also use `@echo off` to disable echo:

```
@echo off
call mkcp.bat
echo %CLASSPATH%
```

Then just call that batch file from your Python code.

If you want to do it without an intervening batch file try:

```
check_output(['cmd', '/V:ON', '/c', '"@echo off && call mkcp.bat && echo !CLASSPATH!"'])
```

`/V:ON` enables delayed expansion of environment variables when you use `!` for the substitution instead of `%`.

Comment: This is awesome. I will try and let you know the results. Both look like very good solutions. Do you recommend any particular one? [I lost my internet so couldn't get back sooner :) ].

Comment: Use whichever one you prefer: the second one has the advantage that you don't need an external batch file, but it is more limited if you wanted to start making it more complex, e.g. getting multiple vars.

Comment: Fair enough. I am using the second one for now, suits me just fine. Thanks a ton man :). (And, I don't have access to a windows machine rt now, will do a final test and accept this on monday). :)